# Integrate QT and OpenCV in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv

Sorry If you feel that this is an already asked question. But I googled for more than 2 days any tried lots of solution which given through stackoverflow and referred lots of tutorials. But I couldn't get a proper idea.

I am already working in a project which use c++(visual studio) with opencv which I am developing as my university project. I have developing this for last 2 months. But now I want to add a better UI.(Previously I considered only on the functionality) So I decided to move into QT. I'm new to QT. So I did some google search.

I know that I can do this with the QT creator. But I want to do this in visual studio as the functionality of my project is bit complex. What I already know is I have to build opencv with Qt using cmake. I followed few tutorials. But most of the tutorials use mingw and QT creator.

http://www.anlak.com/build-debug-opencv-vs2010/

Accoring to above tutorial I generated a visual studio project using cmake. But when I tried to open that solution file my visual studio becomes not-responding. I can't figure out the reason.

I tried two days and I couldn't find a proper tutorial which describes integration of QT and opencv in visual studio. So can someone give me the instruction to integrate QT and Opencv in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Qt Visual Studio Add-In is what you need to get this done. You can download it from https://qt-project.org/downloads.

Then follow the instruction here : http://doc.qt.digia.com/vs-add-in-1.1.7/index.html

I got it to work after just reading the first section.

I also tried the other way, using OpenCV in Qt-creator. It's really painful and I couldn't get it to work. It is much easier to do this in Visual Studio.